# Getting Error Segmentation fault

Tags: c, data-structures, error-handling

My program works fine but has a strange bug... the last line on the input cannot be blank otherwise it throws the error Segmentation fault (core dumped)... Any idea why that would be happening?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM 25
#define LEN 1000
int stringCompare(char str1[],char str2[]);
void stringCopy(char str1[],char str2[]);

int main()
{
    char tmp[25];
    int i=0,j=0;
    char Strings[NUM][LEN];

    printf("enter %d strings, one at a time:\n", NUM);

    for(i=0;i<NUM;++i)
    {
        printf("String %d : ",(i+1));
        fgets(Strings[i],LEN-2,stdin);
    }

    puts("these are the strings you entered:");

    for(i=0;i<NUM;++i)
    {
        printf("%s",Strings[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<NUM-1;j++)
        {
            if(stringCompare(Strings[j],Strings[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                stringCopy(tmp,Strings[j]);
                stringCopy(Strings[j],Strings[j+1]);
                stringCopy(Strings[j+1],tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Output sorted list */
    puts("These are the strings alphabetical order:");
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",Strings[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int stringCompare(char str1[],char str2[]){
    int i=0,flag=0;
    while(str1[i]!='\0' && str2[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(str1[i]!=str2[i]){
            return str1[i] - str2[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void stringCopy(char str1[],char str2[]){
    int i=0;
    while(str2[i]!='\0'){
        str1[i] = str2[i];
        i++;
    }

    str1[i]='\0';
}
```

Comment: Is that how your code looks in your editor? Please make it neater! (I corrected your question mark-up)

Comment: sorry I used Ctrl + O instead of Ctrl + K here I have edited it

Comment: It's still a mess - no indentation makes it very hard to read.

Comment: is it better now? Sorry about all this

Comment: Still your < are being shown as &lt; it is quite confusing in a C code. By the way, your code looks like C despite C++ tag.

Comment: it shows up correctly to me... also i changed the tags

Comment: Can you see why I am getting an error if the last line on my input is a blank?

Comment: Probably not related, but the array `tmp` should be the same size as your strings, which is 1000 (or `LEN`).

Comment: I just ran your code under gcc-Cygwin. I tried with blank first, blank last, and blank middle inputs. The program didn't crash. Can you post the exact inputs and error messages please? Just copy them from the console you were running.

By the way, I tried only short strings. for any string > 25 chars may cause tmp to crash.

Comment: unluddite - That fixed my problem... All I had to do was change it to 1000... I had 25 because I was entering 25 lines including the ones that were blank.. Thank you

Comment: So that must mean you were entering strings longer than 25 characters as your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue that I see in the above code is that you have an array of strings with a maximum length of 1000 and you use a temporary array to swap them, however the temporary array is of size 25, and you may potentially try to copy a string of length 1000 into it causing a buffer overrun.

```
tmp[25];
```

should be

```
tmp[LEN];
```

If at least one of the strings in your input is longer than 23 characters (subtracting 2 for `'\0'` and `'\n'`, your program may exhibit undefined behavior when you copy one of these long strings into `tmp`.